# NSURLConnection cannot connect to remote IP

Tags: objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I have a SpringBoot application that I have running in a docker container on a remote machine (it's actually a little box right beside my Mac, but anyway...). I also have an instance running as a SpringBoot application using bootRun locally on my Mac. These instances are not connected in any way. I have a small iOS test app for accepting push notifications that makes a REST call out to an endpoint exposed by this SB application. I have a physical iPhone connected which Xcode installs the app onto.

If I point the iOS app REST call at my locally running bootRun instance using the IP address of my Mac, the call works fine and registers and everything is great. But, if I point the iOS the REST call at my remote machine running the Docker instances, the call fails. However, if I perform a `curl` command from the terminal, with the identical URL and payload, it works fine. So there is no firewall issue or anything like that. The error reported is:

```
2017-10-04 14:16:18.907472+0100 IosNotificationApp[563:28094] TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x1c416a080]: 1:61 Err(61)
2017-10-04 14:16:18.907716+0100 IosNotificationApp[563:28094] Task <7111CDD1-CB81-410E-B928-AE46E6964184>.<0> HTTP load failed (error code: -1004 [1:61])
2017-10-04 14:16:18.908426+0100 IosNotificationApp[563:28093] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1004
2017-10-04 14:16:18.918332+0100 IosNotificationApp[563:28048] Received response: (null), data: (null)
2017-10-04 14:16:18.918822+0100 IosNotificationApp[563:28048] Failed to register.: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1c0252330 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://111.222.3.4:1234/ios-notification-server/register, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://111.222.3.4:1234/ios-notification-server/register, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://111.222.3.4:1234/ios-notification-server/register, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://111.222.3.4:1234/ios-notification-server/register, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.}
```

Here is my `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` function:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken {

    NSString *newToken = [deviceToken description];
    newToken = [newToken stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    newToken = [newToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"Device token is: %@", newToken);

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://111.222.3.4:1234/ios-notification-server/register"];
    NSString *body =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"foo\":\"bar\",\"deviceToken\":\"%@\"}", newToken];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"Bearer custom.token" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                NSURLResponse *response,
                                NSError *connectionError) {

                NSLog(@"Received response: %@, data: %@", response, data);

                if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Successfully registered");
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Failed to register.: %@", connectionError);
                }
            }] resume];
}
```

Nothing registers on the remote server as a failed authentication or anything, it just doesn't seem to be issuing the call at all. Does anyone have any idea why Xcode would be cauing this to happen when calling an IP that isn't the machine's locally assigned one? Is there anything built-in to Xcode that could help my diagnose what is going on?

Comment: -1004 is `NSURLErrorCannotConnectToHost`.

Comment: And just so we understand, you're saying you can `curl` from your mac to this box, but that the iOS device cannot connect at all (though it is on wifi and can connect to the Mac)?

Comment: Unrelated, I'd suggest retiring `NSURLConnection` and using `NSURLSession` instead. It's just as simple as your `sendAsynchronousRequest`. `NSURLConnection` is deprecated.

Comment: My Mac is 192.168.1.x and the remote box is 192.168.2.x.  Yes, I can successfully curl from my Mac.  The iPhone is connected to my Mac via cable.

Comment: I updated to NSURLSession thinking that maybe it could be related, but reverted back once it made no difference.  This iOS app is something we have for test purposes, I am not a iOS developer.

Comment: I'd retire `NSURLConnection` code, regardless. It's unlikely the problem, but no good is going to come from using a deprecated API.

Comment: Thanks, good advice.  I'll update my question to include NSURLSession in my function.

Comment: Yeah, but I think the problem is a more basic connectivity question. You said that the iPhone is connected to the Mac, but it's on wifi, too, right?

Comment: Yeah, its on the same wifi network as the Mac.

Comment: I think I just cracked it, in my Sharing settings of my Mac, for Internet Sharing, I enabled "To computers using: iPhone USB".  I don't understand why I wouldn't have needed that when connecting to the local bootRun application.  Anyway, thanks @Rob for your help and steering me down the right path!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a physical device, go to `System Preferences -> Sharing`. Click `Internet Sharing`, and enable `To computers using: iPhone USB`.

For iPad, I'd assume you'd enable `iPad USB`.